# Best way to keep changes in django-admin for future releases?

Tags: django, django-admin

I was wondering what's the best way to modify django-admin? That is, the best way to modify it and keep compatibility with future releases?

Specifically I'm reffering to the search_fields where using (=field) gets converted to field__iexact in the query construction when I need field__exact ?

I just want to make modifications in a way that they are applicable in future releases.

Thanks,
Angel

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the default search, the place where the __iexact lookup is constructed is actually in the core of the admin system. So it's not solvable by implementing your own admin or meta derivations.

You could try to [override the admin template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and inlude your own search form, but this will require a lot of recoding as you will need to hack in some javascript in the list display, you'll also need to find a way to fiddle with the list's queryset. This however is very likely to be supported throughout the whole 1.x release. It can however be you need to adapt your template a bit if you want to support new admin features of future releases.